# Newbie with questions about Flash Loans

Tags: flash-loans

I am a newbie to flash loans and I am grateful if you could answer my questions below

1. Can one hundred thousand people flash loan the same crypto currency pair at the same time?
2. When doing a flash loan does the volume and liquidity matter? If so why?
3. With 0.1 eth can I flash loan 100 Eth? Or 10000 eth?
4. How do you calculate how much eth is needed as gas fee?
5. Where the best website to find someone to create a flash loan for me?
6. Is there a website/screener that shows you all the DEX prices?
7. Is it better to flash loan with big crypto pairs or the med/ small cap pairs?
8. Can you manually do crypto arbitrage between DEXs? If so how?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Depends on how much loan can borrower provide
2. Can you elaborate on this?
3. Each provider has its own rules regarding how much you can take.
4. Depends.
5. Please stay away from this. [99% of flashloans smart contracts are scam](https://medium.com/remix-ide/remix-in-youtube-crypto-scams-71c338da32d)
6. [Dex Screener](https://dexscreener.com/)
7. Smaller pairs have higher volatility, thus it's easier to find profitable margins between exchanges.
8. How? Buy where it's cheap and sell where it's not cheap. Can you do it? Highly unlikely, bot is always a better solution.

Comment: Hi Kaneda, thank you for replying to my questions, question 2 can I flash loan a pair for example has only 33k in volume and 13k in liquidity?

Answer (score 0):

Just study the docs for flashloans from different providers, start with Aave, that should make things more clear to you.

8. very rarely, bot is a must

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).